# Converting .webm to mp4 produces "incorrect parameters" error

Tags: ffmpeg

I am attempting to convert a particular video from webm to mp4 using:
`ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -i $input -r 24 $output`, but I am getting an error:

```
[libx264 @ 0x55c8801feb00] width not divisible by 2 (1025x525)
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
[aac @ 0x55c880283340] Qavg: 110.549
[aac @ 0x55c880283340] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
```

Is there a solution I can use that will be generic for all videos including this video file.